# Leksah like on-change build in vim

Tags: vim, language-agnostic, build-process

I've just given Leksah a try for Haskell development it's nice and all but I'm a Vim man really, but I do really love the little lower right hand pane that re-builds and displays status on every change I make to the source.

It's applicable to many langauges really but is there an existing solution that does this? Something like a deamon that would look for changes in a source file and then re-build/interprert the source files and continuously display the results?

I'm using a tiling window manager so direct console based output would be as good as any.

If not I suppose it'd be a fun holiday project :)

Comment: -1 for now, because it's really hard to tell what you're asking for.  I'll remove my downvote if you can improve the question.

Comment: I suppose it's a continuous build tool I'm looking for, the system in seems to call the GHC build process and then pipe the results out, I the best solution would be to set up a repository and set up something like Hudson for it. The immediacy of seeing the results was useful more than anything I've knocked up a little script to monitor timestamps and create a similar effect in nay case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a lovely solution to this called 'Flymake' https://github.com/kana/vim-flymake/ based on an emacs utility it's as simple as pointing to the compiler/static analysis tool you want to use and then writing regexes to identify the warnings and errors it outputs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something that will do continuous builds and display the results in vim.  That made me think of the red-green-refactor cycle, and that led me to [this project](https://github.com/reinh/vim-makegreen).  You still have to manually invoke the build, but it'll turn your status line red or green depending on build status.

Comment: That's not quite what I had in mind but that's a nice little plugin in any case.